# Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, delayed-job

Delayed jobs service is stopping after less than 1 hour of its starting time with the following log:

```
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:26.580458 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:26+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Starting job worker
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:26.664929 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:26+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41019) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.342994 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41019) COMPLETED after 0.6779
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.346526 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41020) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.470858 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41020) COMPLETED after 0.1242
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.474937 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41024) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.603043 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41024) COMPLETED after 0.1280
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.606702 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41025) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.725715 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41025) COMPLETED after 0.1189
I, [2018-02-26T06:00:27.728021 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:00:27+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] 4 jobs processed at 3.4871 j/s, 0 failed
I, [2018-02-26T06:14:48.287220 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:14:48+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41027) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:14:48.414079 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:14:48+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41027) COMPLETED after 0.1267
I, [2018-02-26T06:14:48.416335 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:14:48+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] 1 jobs processed at 7.3771 j/s, 0 failed
I, [2018-02-26T06:16:33.492435 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:16:33+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41028) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:16:33.613684 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:16:33+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41028) COMPLETED after 0.1211
I, [2018-02-26T06:16:33.615953 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:16:33+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] 1 jobs processed at 7.8121 j/s, 0 failed
I, [2018-02-26T06:22:33.853678 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:22:33+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41030) RUNNING
I, [2018-02-26T06:22:33.967338 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:22:33+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Job ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::DelayedJobAdapter::JobWrapper (id=41030) COMPLETED after 0.1136
I, [2018-02-26T06:22:33.970307 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:22:33+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] 1 jobs processed at 8.2735 j/s, 0 failed
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:24.595215 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:24+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:24.593926', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:24.593351' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:24.593398') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:29.597026 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:29+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:29.596061', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:29.595477' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:29.595524') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:34.598775 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:34+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:34.597856', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:34.597278' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:34.597325') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:39.600772 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:39+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:39.599713', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:39.599063' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:39.599110') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:44.602546 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:44+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:44.601568', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:44.601024' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:44.601072') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:49.604286 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:49+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:49.603369', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:49.602808' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:49.602863') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:54.606189 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:54+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:54.605111', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:54.604563' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:54.604613') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:38:59.608610 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:38:59+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:38:59.607243', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:38:59.606483' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:38:59.606539') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:39:04.610465 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:39:04+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:39:04.609457', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:39:04.608876' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:39:04.608926') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
I, [2018-02-26T06:39:09.612201 #11439]  INFO -- : 2018-02-26T06:39:09+0400: [Worker(delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439)] Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor: UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_at = '2018-02-26 02:39:09.611263', locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439' WHERE id IN (SELECT  "delayed_jobs"."id" FROM "delayed_jobs" WHERE ((run_at <= '2018-02-26 02:39:09.610721' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2018-02-25 22:39:09.610770') OR locked_by = 'delayed_job host:myhost pid:11439') AND failed_at IS NULL)  ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE) RETURNING *
```

**database.yml**

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 database: myapp
 port: 5432
 pool: 5
 username: username
 password: password
 reconnect: true
```

Please can anyone just explain the reason of this error and how to avoid it:

```
Error while reserving job: PG::ConnectionBad: PQconsumeInput() server closed the connection unexpectedly
```

**Update:**

I believe this issue is not related to delayed jobs, since I'm getting same error while I'm doing some normal DB queries. So DB is restarting for some reason and this why delayed job service is stopping.

As per commented by @LaurenzAlbe , below are some issues found in `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log`:

```
LOG:  connection received: host=10.10.10.15 port=57322
LOG:  replication connection authorized: user=MyDBUser
FATAL:  must be superuser or replication role to start walsender
LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:06:18.911 user=MyDBUser database=MyDB host=127.0.0.1 port=34040
./systemd: 36: kill: Operation not permitted
WARNING:  skipping "delayed_jobs" --- only table or database owner can analyze it
```

Comment: Maybe a firewall closing the connection for you. Look into the PostgreSQL log to see if the database server is at fault.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I run `tail -1000 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log` and found all 1000 lines are repeating `./systemd: 47: kill: No such process` again and again.

Comment: And immediately before that? What does `systemctl status` say about the service?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I believe delayed jobs have a memory leak issue, which is solved by using `config.cache_classes = true` because delayed jobs keeps reloading classes every now and then.

I had the same issue where delayed job process used more than 90%+ of memory and it crashed with the same error, even though I had cached classes, but I was running delayed jobs without `RAILS_ENV`, which caused them to load in development and ignore the other environment settings.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be caused by:

1. Rails's database `idle_timeout` setting, which is 300 seconds by default. This means that if a connection is idle for more than 300 seconds, the server will close it.
2. PgBouncer `client_idle_timeout` setting. This setting controls how long a connection can be idle before PgBouncer closes it. If this setting is set too low, it can cause the same errors as Rails's idle_timeout.
3. PostgreSQL `idle_session_timeout` settings (from PostgreSQL 14) and `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`(for sessions that were idle in transaction).
4. TCP or other network or firewall timeouts(e.g. there is a case of the timeout in Azure Cloud)

And to solve this problem, there are a few possible solutions:

0. Speed up slow processing
1. Increase the `idle_timeout`(or another guilty timeout) setting to a higher value to prevent a server from closing idle connections too soon.
2. Add a database setting called reaping_frequency: 10, which will clear and restore connections more frequently to prevent them from becoming idle.
3. Add manual reconnection, like the code snippet below, which releases the connection and re-establishes it before saving a record to the database.

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.release_connection
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
      # save record in database
    end
```

Links:

[(1)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html)[(2)](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/DatabaseConfigurations/HashConfig/reaping_frequency)[(3)](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#postgres-connection-corruption)[(4)](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.4.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L283) Info about `reaping_frequency`

[(5)](https://juanitofatas.com/series/rails/active-record-connection-pool)[(6)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) Info about Rails's `idle_timeout`

[(7)](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3128)[(8)](https://github.com/grosser/parallel/issues/62)[(9)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65242944/11736429) Solutions with manual reconnection